# In dotnet project files, is there a $(Variable) for the user home directory?

Tags: .net-core

I would like to reference some files in a `dotnet` project file. The files are expected to be relative to the user's home directory.

However, this (for example) is not allowed:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="~/some/folder/in/home/project.fsproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I can reference other folders, such as `$(OutDir)` and `$(PublishDir)`, but is there a variable for the user home folder provided?

It must work across platforms.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's none, as normally you'd not rely on such paths existing. If you really need to do this and cannot use relative paths, perhaps you can use the `$(OS)` variable to set the appropriate path?

Comment: [Sounds like an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... Why does your build need to rely on files in the user's home directory?

Comment: @omajid Unfortunately yes, because not every software package / dependency can legally or practically be included on Nuget, NPM, etc.

Answer (score 1):

When using msbuild, all environment variables are available as msbuild properties.

This includes environment variables like `$HOME`. You should just be able to do:

```
<ProjectReference Include="$(HOME)/some/folder/in/home/project.fsproj" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to leverage `Directory.Build.props` files. These can be placed in to root of the project folder like this:

```xml
<Project>
 <PropertyGroup>
  <SomeCustomSetting>/home/your_username_here/</SomeCustomSetting>
 </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Then they can be added to `.gitignore`